# I want to add a real time to my node.js project and i want to use it in if-else situation

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, node-modules, ejs

I am making a project about daily newspaper for hotels. For example I want to display all activities in daily-newspaper tab on website, but also in homepage I want to display the close activites, for example if it's last 2 hours for karaoke, I want to display it in homepage with ejsif. All data is fake for project.

```js
const dailyData = [
    {id:1, name:"Yoga Lesson" ,time: "10:30 AM", place:"Show Lounge", date:"26.07"},
    {id:2, name:"Zumba" ,time: "16:30 PM", place:"Pool Area", date:"28.07"},
    {id:3, name:"Disco" ,time: "12:00 AM ", place:"Eclipse Bar", date:"30.07"},  
]

app.use("/daily", function(req,res) {
    res.render("daily", {
        dailyData: dailyData
    })
});
```

So data is ready to use it in ".ejs" file.

```html
<ul>
    <% dailyData.forEach(data => { %>
        <% if (data.time < ("I need help here")) { %>
         
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Here I don't know with what I should compare the data.time. I want to display the data, if it's closer than 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having two different time properties, consider using [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can modify your dailyData objects to look something like this:

```js
{id:1, name:"Yoga Lesson", time: 1690392600000, place:"Show Lounge"}
```

*Beware that JS uses milliseconds instead of seconds, so you'll have to multiply the time given you by some converters by 1000.*
When it comes to rendering this, you can modify the format using `DateTimeFormat`, like this example:

```js
date = data.time;
options = {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  timeZone: "Australia/Sydney",
};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-AU", options).format(date));
```

This makes comparing super easy.

```js
if (date >= Date.now() && date <= Date.now() + 7200000) {
  console.log("Within two hours from now!");
} else { console.log("Not within two hours from now."); }
```